# Batch program to rename file which has spaces in file name

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, rename

I am trying to rename a file with the name `AQT and Toad Users.xlsx` using the following command

```
rename H:\AQT^ and^ Toad^ Users.xlsx  AQT.xlsx
```

It's giving a syntax error, I've used `^` to escape space.

Can anyone suggest what’s wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ren  "h:\AQT and Toad Users.xlsx" "whateveryournewnameis"
```

The quotes are required if there are spaces in the name.

Comment: **Any idea how to do this for multiple files ?**

if multiple file names contain a string with spaces that i want to replace:

 * file 1: "file1 UNWANTED TEXT.csv"
 * file 2: "file2_x UNWANTED TEXT_2014.xls"


I want to rename all files that contain the UNWANTED TEXT by replacing the UNWANTED TEXT with a string value.

Comment: @rockspider You should ask your own question. It's free.

Comment: @ magoo. Good suggestion, I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396610/how-to-rename-files-in-windows-cmd-command-prrompt?noredirect=1#comment112107969_63396610)