# How to rename files in Windows CMD (command prompt)

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

Renaming files in Windows explorer is easy but when you need to rename many files it can become quite tedious. A command prompt (terminal) makes it easier.

Comment: The usage of shareware file manager __Total Commander__ makes it very easy to rename lots of files (or folders) in a folder or a folder tree or spread over all drives very easy without any coding skills and being nevertheless extremely powerful with its built-in awesome __Multi-rename tool__.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks for the suggestion, that sounds like a nice tool. Personally, i prefer using command line (and i dont like installing 3rd party tools all the time :)

Answer (score 17):

In order to rename any file you need to `cd` into your folder directory and then just type one of these: ex,

- `Desktop> ren "My file" "Your file"`
- `Desktop> rename "hello.txt" "goodbye.txt"`
- `Desktop> ren "why.txt" "because.docx"`

and click the Enter button

Answer (score 10):

**Renaming 1 file in cmd is very easy:**
In this example we have a `sample1.txt` and we want to change its name to `sample2.txt`:

```
    in command prompt type:
    c:\temp> ren sample1.txt sample2.txt [enter]
```

Let's say the filename is `sample1-some-unwanted-text-1234.txt` and we want to change it to `sample1.txt`:

```
    in command prompt, type:
    c:\temp> ren sample1-some-unwanted-text-1234.txt sample1.txt
```

**Renaming 1 file by replacing multiple unwanted characters using a star**:
Let's say the filename is `sample1-some-unwanted-text-1234.txt` and we want to change it to `sample1.txt` without having to type the whole filename:

```
    in command prompt:
    c:\temp> ren sample1*.txt sample1.txt
```

This * basically means *any characters* inbetween `sample1` and `.txt` will be replaced.

**Renaming multiple files with similar names**
If you want to rename multiple files, i.e. `sample1 2020-08-01.txt`, `sample2 2020-08-05.txt`, `sample3 2020-08-10.txt`,`sample4 2020-08-13.txt`, you want to keep the first 7 characters you want to get rid of the dates:

```
    in command prompt:
    c:\temp> ren sample?*.txt sample?.txt
```

In this example, you want to keep the word `sample` and the number X (where X can be any number or character). Using a ? will leave the number in place and * instructs the rename-command to replace any characters in between `sampleX` and `.txt`

*Warning: It happens very quickly that a command prompt rename operation renames too many files and you can't undo it. So, when renaming multiple files it is advisable to make a copy of all the files you want to rename, put them in a temp folder, then run your rename commands in the temp folder, and when you're certain that it works, go back and rename the original files.*

Comment: How can this be linked to a question about renaming files with spaces in the filename? You have not used the correct syntax, which is `REN "[drive:][path]filename1" "filename2"`, you should use doublequotes at any time where you cannot guarantee that `[path]filename1` and/or `filename2` does not contain a space, or any other poisonous character. For robustness/safety, always enclose paths/filenames within doublequotes.

Comment: ok i removed the link to the other question.
yeah i agree, using quotes is a good idea
but you dont need to specify the [drive][path] if you want to simply rename a file in the current folder.

Comment: `ren` command can handle very simple cases. Better throw cmd away and use powershell which allows you to do arbitrary renaming easily

Comment: @phuclv i totally agree, powershell is much more powerful, but I sometimes use cmd for simple stuff and i think many people still use cmd so i hope this post will help somebody

Answer (score -1):

```
for %f in (*) do (
    if %~z1 gtr 0 (
        set "content="
        for /f "delims=" %a in (%f) do set "content=!content!%a"
        set "content=!content:oldword=newword!"
        echo !content! > %f
    )
)
```